# Find a limit using integral

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1\cdot3^{\frac{1}{n}} + \ldots + n\cdot3^{\frac{n}{n}}}{(n + 1)^2};
$$

At first I think we need to factor out $\frac{1}{n}$ and we get the following sum:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{k\cdot3^{\frac{k}{n}}}{\left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2}
$$

But at this moment I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not successfully "factor out" the $\frac1n$. That would have been $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k\cdot 3^{\frac kn}}{(n+1)\left(1+\frac1n\right)}$$

However, if you want to use the hint the ideal thing to look at is $$\text{initial thing}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-2}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac kn\cdot3^{\frac kn}\right)$$

Now, in the right-hand side there is a Riemann sum and a thing that tends to $1$.